# Windows UWP app for Windows 8 and 10 both

Tags: windows, win-universal-app

I am new to Windows app development and going to develop the first Windows app. Our client wants an UWP app that supports both Windows 8 and 10. I am planning to use a Windows 8.1 machine with Visual studio 2015 for development.

When I create a project for that should I create it as a Windows 8 Universal app or a Windows Universal app? From what I have read if I create a Windows Universal app I think it'll work only on Windows 10 only. So I guess I should create it as a Windows 8 app. Will that work in Windows 10 without any changes? Will that be available for both Windows 8 and 10 appstores?

Please share your knowledge and experience about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a single project, you have to use a Windows 8.1 project template.  See screenshot below. It's a little confusing as this template is also called "Universal Windows" but mind the version number 8.1. It's in the template subfolder Windows 8. It will run on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 but not on Windows 8. You can make it available to both platforms via Windows appstore. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. So if my client wants to support Windows 8 as well, I'll have to create the Project using VS 2012. Is that correct? That will also be available for 8, 8.1 and 10 in the store right? Any downside of using VS 2012?

Comment: Hi! Correct. Windows 8.0 apps can be created in VS2012 only. They will be available on 8.0, 8.1 and 10. I'd recommend to skip 8.0 if possible and instead move forward to a newer version. With 8.1 Universal Apps you have compatibility to Phones.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I haven't used VS 2012. So with that can't I create a Windows Universal app? Do I have to create a Windows phone app separately and tablet/desktop app separately. Is that what you mean?